# Update install JAVA SE developement kit 8(JDK)8 ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: updates, java, android, jdk, android-studio

I was trying to update the JDK on my machine (Ubuntu 14) by downloading the packages on Java official site (this one http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html )

Now  this was in order to install android studio, following the instructions on this page https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

I did what they tell to do, but I encountered 3 problems:
- First, why is there no 32 bit package downloadable? And can I download the 64 anyway and it works (I mean probably not, but the 32 bit is just not existing....)
- Second, I didn’t saw any bash/python file to """install""" the package, so is there a special folder to put it or the home will do?
-Third, all started because my javac -version gave 1.7 as a result (1.8 is needed), but after downloading the package and doing what they do the commands STILL gives version 1.7, which is mainly why I ask this question...

I apologize for my english and my gnu-ignorance, hoping someone has an answer :)

SIDE NOTE: android studio actually blocks with this mistake (JDK8 is needed, I have 7. So the update is not completed)

Ok i found [HowTo: Upgrade java on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508546/howto-upgrade-java-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) this, but.....is there a way that does not rely on official tar downloads? Plus, even though os says java is version 1.8, androidstudio says it's 1.7

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer all your questions, but please break them into separate Q&As in the future. It makes it easier for one person to answer.

1. You seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding in regards to 32-bit. x86 is actually 32-bit. x86 is named after a line of old Intel CPUs (I think), but they didn't really have anything to name 64-bit after, so it became x64.

   - Get the x86 version
2. You'll have to adapt the file names a bit, since Java versions have changed, but this Ask Ubuntu Q&A has very extensive installation instructions: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).
3. As for default Java version, you need to have the one you want as default installed, and then you need to select it as the default. [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version).

   - The command you want, since it looks like you're dealing with `javac`, is:

     ```
     sudo update-alternatives --config javac
     ```
   - Replacing `javac` with `java` will allow you to change defaults there too.

Honestly, I'm having a hard time understanding your question fully, and I see you don't speak English natively. Hopefully, what I have below will make the whole thing easier.

There's an alternative to Oracle's JDK, called OpenJDK. It's a very simple installation, and I believe it sets itself as the default Java version. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: Ok thank you really much for patience and the great explanation! It has been really helpful! I hope to be able to make it work. (again sorry for the mess)

Answer (score 0):

There is Webupd8 PPA for Java, you can install it by entering this one by one in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

For more info, see http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html