# webupd8team ppa errors when installing java (with a 404)

Tags: 16.04, ppa, jdk

Im trying to install java8 in a ubuntu/xenial and im getting this error:

```
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-01-17 12:11:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.94.43.14
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-17 12:11:52--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.19.148.207, 2a02:26f0:8f:28a::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:8f:29a::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.19.148.207|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify edelivery.oracle.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516191232_7550f29a68f58ad4d32325c09fb4821a [following]
--2018-01-17 12:11:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516191232_7550f29a68f58ad4d32325c09fb4821a
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-17 12:11:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My test command is

```
docker run ubuntu:xenial bash -c 'echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list; echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list; apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886; apt-get update; yes | apt-get install oracle-java8-installer'
```

This used to work a couple of days ago but not any more. I tried googling to see if there are any recent issue but couldnt find anything.

Any ideas ?

## Update 1

The package that its trying to download is rescent enough so that its not removed by oracle
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html

Trying to wget the url generated by the `apt-get` command yields the same error

```
root@d4f14185f885:/# wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516191232_7550f29a68f58ad4d32325c09fb4821a
--2018-01-17 12:25:20--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516191232_7550f29a68f58ad4d32325c09fb4821a
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.94.43.14
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2018-01-17 12:25:21 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

but downloading the package without the `AuthParam` is a success (but then the certs check needs to be disabled)

```
root@d4f14185f885:/# wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
--2018-01-17 12:26:10--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.94.43.14
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-17 12:26:10--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2.19.148.207, 2a02:26f0:8f:28a::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:8f:29a::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2.19.148.207|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify edelivery.oracle.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2018-01-17 12:26:10--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz.2'

jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz.2                                        100%[===================================================================================================================================================================>]   5.18K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-01-17 12:26:10 (61.3 MB/s) - 'jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz.2' saved [5307/5307]
```

Comment: Same issue that I'm having here: https://askubuntu.com/q/996774/783699 The PPA isn't maintained by Oracle themselves, but rather a third party (WebUpd8). Yesterday (2018-01-17) Oracle released 9.0.4 and it broke apt for JDK 8 and 9. There will be workarounds soon and eventually they (WebUpd8) will update the PPA. This seems to happen after most JDK releases.