# Set Oracle JDK 8 as default JAVA - update fails

Tags: updates, java, jdk

I've installed java and all it's additionals some weeks ago and could use it via eclipse with no problem. It still works but the last days everytime I boot my laptop an update shows up "Set Oracle JDK 8 as default JAVA". I press "Install" and then the installation fails.

Wtf is this. How do I get rid of this "update"?
It shows up all the time -.-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version)

Comment: No it isn't. If you read my question you see why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install JDK 9 via apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996774/cannot-install-jdk-9-via-apt)